# xcscope responds "File does not have expected format"

Tags: emacs, elisp, cscope

When trying to find a file using command **cscope-find-file** inside emacs the following message is displayed

```
"File does not have expected format"
```

But when the same is tried using the cscope command prompt in cygwin The following message is displayed. On pressing enter key the file is opened.

```
"/cygdrive/x/src/lib/proxy/controller.h" [dos format] 201 lines, 64
47 characters
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How to emulate the same behaviour in emacs, Below is the elisp code.

```
(defun cscope-find-this-file (symbol)
  "Locate a file."
  (interactive (list
        (let (cscope-no-mouse-prompts)
          (cscope-prompt-for-symbol "Find this file: " t))
        ))
  (let ( (cscope-adjust nil) )   ;; Disable fuzzy matching.
    (setq cscope-symbol symbol)
    (cscope-call (format "Finding file: %s" symbol)
         (list "-7" symbol) nil 'cscope-process-filter
         'cscope-process-sentinel)
    ))
```

Any pointers on what to modify in the above code is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a spotted bug but the patch has not been released yet.
cf this [discussion](http://sourceforge.net/p/cscope/bugs/200/) on cscope, you will find a patch.